# Reading a file line-by-line into an array of strings in C

Tags: arrays, c, string, file-io

I'm trying to read the following file line by line into an array of strings where each line is an element of the array:

```
AATGC
ATGCC
GCCGT
CGTAC
GTACG
TACGT
ACGTA
CGTAC
GTACG
TACGA
ACGAA
```

My code is as follows:

```c
void **get_genome(char *filename) {
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
    int c;
    int line_count = 0;
    int line_length = 0;
    for (c = getc(file); c != EOF; c = getc(file)) {
        if (c == '\n') line_count++;
        else line_length++;
    }
    line_length /= line_count;
    rewind(file);

    char **genome = calloc(line_length * line_count, sizeof(char));
    for (int i = 0; i < line_count; i++) {
        genome[i] = calloc(line_length, sizeof(char));
        fscanf(file, "%s\n", genome[i]);
    }

    printf("%d lines of %d length\n", line_count, line_length);

    for (int i = 0; i < line_count; i++)
        printf("%s\n", genome[i]);
}
```

However, for some reason I get garbage output for the first 2 elements of the array. The following is my output:

```
`NP��
�NP��
GCCGT
CGTAC
GTACG
TACGT
ACGTA
CGTAC
GTACG
TACGA
ACGAA
```

Comment: `if (c == '\n') line_count++;` leads to trouble if the last line does not end with a `'\n'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to assume that all lines have the same line length. If such is the case, you still have some problems:

- the memory for the row pointers is allocated incorrectly, it should be

  ```
    char **genome = calloc(line_count, sizeof(char *));
  ```

or better and less error prone:

```
    char **genome = calloc(line_count, sizeof(*genome));
```

- the memory for each row should be one byte longer the the null terminator.
- `\n` is the `fscanf()` format string matches any sequence of whitespace characters. It is redundant as `%s` skips those anyway.
- it is safer to count items separated by white space to avoid miscounting the items if the file contains any blank characters.
- you do not close `file`.
- you do not return the `genome` at the end of the function
- you do not check for errors.

Here is a modified version:

```c
void **get_genome(const char *filename) {
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
        return NULL;
    int line_count = 1;
    int item_count = 0;
    int item_length = -1;
    int length = 0;
    int c;
    while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF) {
        if (isspace(c)) {
            if (length == 0)
                continue;  // ignore subsequent whitespace
            item_count++;
            if (item_length < 0) {
                item_length = length;
            } else
            if (item_length != length) {
                printf("inconsistent item length on line %d\", line_count);
                fclose(file);
                return NULL;
            }
            length = 0;
        } else {   
            length++;
        }
    }
    if (length) {
        printf("line %d truncated\n", line_count);
        fclose(file);
        return NULL;
    }
    rewind(file);

    char **genome = calloc(item_count, sizeof(*genome));
    if (genome == NULL) {
        printf("out of memory\n");
        fclose(file);
        return NULL;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < item_count; i++) {
        genome[i] = calloc(item_length + 1, sizeof(*genome[i]));
        if (genome[i] == NULL) {
            while (i > 0) {
                free(genome[i]);
            }
            free(genome);
            printf("out of memory\n");
            fclose(file);
            return NULL;
        }
        fscanf(file, "%s", genome[i]);
    }
    fclose(file);

    printf("%d items of %d length on %d lines\n",
           item_count, item_length, line_count);

    for (int i = 0; i < item_count; i++)
        printf("%s\n", genome[i]);

    return genome;
}
```

Comment: @chqle Why scanf?

Comment: @P__J__: I kept the OP's solution to skip the white space and read the genome entry. One could skip read the input one byte at a time, just like for the initial phase.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>  char **genome = calloc(line_length * line_count, sizeof(char));
> ```

must be

```
char **genome = calloc(line_count, sizeof(char*));
```

or more 'secure'

```
char **genome = calloc(line_count, sizeof(*genome));
```

in case you change the type of *genome*

else the allocated block if not enough long if you are in 64b because *line_count* is 5 rather than 8, so you write out of it with an undefined behavior

You also need to return *genome* at the end of the function

It was also possible to not count the number of lines and to use `realloc` to increment your array when reading the file

Answer (score 0):

As I see the lines have the same length. Your function should inform the caller how many lines have been read. There is no need of reading the file twice. There is no need of `calloc` (which is more expensive function). Always check the result of the memory allocation functions.

Here is a bit different version of the function:

```
char **get_genome(char *filename, size_t *line_count) {
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
    int c;
    size_t line_length = 0;
    char **genome = NULL, **tmp;

    *line_count = 0;
    if(file)
    {
        while(1)
        {
            c = getc(file);
            if( c == EOF || c == '\n') break;
            line_length++;
        }    
        rewind(file);

        while(1)
        {
            char *line = malloc(line_length + 1);
            if(line)
            {
                if(!fgets(line, line_length + 1, file))
                {
                    free(line);
                    break;
                }
                line[line_length] = 0;
                tmp = realloc(genome, (*line_count + 1) * sizeof(*genome));
                if(tmp)
                {
                    genome = tmp;
                    genome[*line_count] = line;
                    *line_count += 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    // do some memory free magic
                }
            }
        }
        fclose(file);
    }
    return genome;
}
```